# I have a problem with the db_assembler. bash mysqladmin not found

Tags: azerothcore

even so I can access my sql database, seeing it running in my services and created the user acore with all rights I have this error when using db_assembler.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WZ5s.png

Then the window gets closed I configured the config.sh earlier but it didnt got me far. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem, and solved by editing the Path variable in Windows. The error is caused because the 'mysqladmin.exe' file is not being found by the AzCore installation script.

To fix it, you need to add the directory that file is found in (usually C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\ on a default install) to the Path variable. To do that, go to Advanced System Settings under System in the Control Panel, click the Environment Variables button, select Path from the list up the top, and click the Edit button. Then click New, add the path to the 'mysqladmin.exe' file, and OK out of there. You'll need to reboot, restart the MySQL Server service, and then retry the AzCore DB installation script.